# How do I move my text formating to CSS when formating changes a lot even in one line of text?

Tags: html, css, fonts, styles

I understand that font formating is supposed to be done in CSS, and not in the HTML file, and I want to conform as much as possible, but how do I deal with lots of font changes in one or two lines like this?

```
<li><p><b><FONT COLOR="FF0000">NEWS </FONT>(May 2012):</p>
<p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LostLangtons">Lost Langtons has a new Facebook page!</a></b></p></li>
```

I could set the `<li>` element in CSS to bold text but how would i make half of it red?
If i created a second css element for the red font then that would mean id have to place it within the paragraph tags which isnt right either is it?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing complicated:

in css:

```
.red{
color:#FF0000;
}
```

in html:

```
<li><p><b><label class="red">NEWS </label>(May 2012):</p>
```

Like this you will be able to change the redness of all your red labels all at once :)

Comment: thanks, and its ok for the <label> element to be within the <p> tags?

Comment: Add `p { font-weight: bold; }` to get rid of the `<b>` tag too!